# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, ssl, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to access my REST API. However, when I put my API behind ssl and access it by `http://myhost/myapi` then I get this error:

Do I need to do something extra now that my API is behind SSL?

Here is how I connect:

```
private final String API = "https://myhost/myapi";

private final RestAdapter REST_ADAPTER = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setServer(API)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .build();

01-10 09:49:55.621    2076-2100/com.myapp.mobile D/Retrofit﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:401)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:90)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:48)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:287)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:222)
            at $Proxy12.signin(Native Method)
            at com.myapp.loginactivity$3.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:143)
            at com.myapp.loginactivity$3.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:136)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:595)
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
            at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:90)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:48)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:287)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:222)
            at $Proxy12.signin(Native Method)
            at com.myapp.LoginActivity$3.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:143)
            at com.myapp.LoginActivity$3.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:136)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: have you solved this problem ?

Comment: If you haven't already solved that, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436459/4261176

Answer (score 17):

The reason this occur is the JVM/Dalvik haven't not confidence in the  CA certificates in the system or in the user  certificate stores.

To fix this with Retrofit, If you are used okhttp, with another client it's very  similar.
You've to do:

A). Create a cert store contain public Key of CA. To do this you need to launch next script for *nix. 
You need openssl install in your machine, and download from https://www.bouncycastle.org/ the jar bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar. Download this version not 
other, the version 1.5x is not compatible with android 4.0.4.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: cert2Android<CA cert PEM file>"
  exit 1
fi

CACERT=$1
BCJAR=bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar

TRUSTSTORE=mytruststore.bks
ALIAS=`openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in $CACERT`

if [ -f $TRUSTSTORE ]; then
    rm $TRUSTSTORE || exit 1
fi

echo "Adding certificate to $TRUSTSTORE..."
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias $ALIAS \
      -file $CACERT \
      -keystore $TRUSTSTORE -storetype BKS \
      -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
      -providerpath $BCJAR \
      -storepass secret

echo "" 
echo "Added '$CACERT' with alias '$ALIAS' to $TRUSTSTORE..."
```

B). Copy the file truststore mytruststore.bks  in res/raw of your project
[image: truststore location]

C). Setting SSLContext of the connection:

```
.............
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
try {
    KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
    ksTrust.load(instream, "secret".toCharArray());

    // TrustManager decides which certificate authorities to use.
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ksTrust);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
.................
```

Comment: If you are using `retrofit` you have to attach this `OkHttpClient` as suggested here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/265. Also I have found this only works with: `bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar` otherwise you get the `wrong version of keystore error`

Comment: Cannot resolve method `okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(..)`, now should be `client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()).build();`

Comment: @Fernando can you help with the server part, what cerfiticate to use there, shoould it be the same?\

Comment: i am unable to generate file i create bash file but it only goes to if ...whats the condition for it

Answer (score 7):

You basically have four potential solutions to fix a "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: " exception on Android

1. Trust all certificates. Don't do this, unless you really know what you're doing.
2. Create a custom SSLSocketFactory that trusts only your certificate. This works as long as you know exactly which servers you're going to connect to, but as soon as you need to connect to a new server with a different SSL certificate, you'll need to update your app.
3. Create a Keystore file that contains Android's "master list" of certificates, then add your own. If any of those certs expire down the road, you are responsible for updating them in your app. I can't think of a reason to do this.
4. Create a custom SSLSocketFactory that uses the built-in certificate KeyStore, but falls back on an alternate KeyStore for anything that fails to verify with the default.
   This is well explained in [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872)

Also, I want to elaborate more to point number 1.
We can selectively skip some domain using manifest network config as explain:

1. Create a file "network_security_config.xml" in xml folder in res folder with following content.

   ```
      <network-security-config xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <domain-config>
             <domain includeSubdomains="true">191.1.1.0</domain>
             <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain</domain>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="system" />
                <certificates src="user" />
            </trust-anchors>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
   ```
2. Add "network_security_config.xml" to application tag in manifest as:

   `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

Thats it..done!!. You successfully skipped the SSL certificate.

Comment: Not Working in android 7.0

Comment: Please elaborate @GauravMandlik. As far this is working in every version from Android 6

Comment: for example my domain is https:// www. google.com , then what should I add in "your_domain" field?

Comment: @KishanSolanki you should add  www. google.com as in your_domain

Comment: @taranjeetsapra I tried different approaches including the one you provided but it didn't work on Android 7. This issue seems to be only appearing onAndroid 7 for me.

Comment: How do you---"Create a custom SSLSocketFactory that trusts only your certificate." ?

Answer (score 6):

This can happen for several reasons, including:

1. The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown
2. The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed
3. The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA

please check out this link for solution:  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

Comment: Yes, I used retrofit + okhttp by then

Comment: I had this same problem, the problem was point 3: "The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA", adding the intermediate CA solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

**Fix for Android N & above:**
I had similar issue and mange to solve it by following steps described in https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

But the config changes, without any complicated code logic, would only work on Android version 24 & above.

**Fix for all version, including version < N:**
So for android lower then N (version 24) the solution is to via code changes as mentioned above. If you are using OkHttp, then follow the customTrust:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways that I know of:

- import the certificate to your app and use it for the connection
- disable certificate checking
- add your certificate to the trusted system certificates in Android
- buy a verified certificate that is accepted by Android

I assume you don't want to pay for this, so I think the most elegant solution is the first one, what can be accomplished this way:

http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: How could I just disable certificate checking?  Wanting to do this only in a test environment.

Comment: How do you "add your certificate to the trusted system certificates in Android"?

Comment: There are several tutorials in the internet about that. Here is one for you: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/03/16/manually-install-ssl-certificate-in-android-jelly-bean/

Answer (score 1):

The SSL is not properly configured.  Those trustAnchor errors usually mean that the trust store cannot be found.  Check your configuration and make sure you are actually pointing to the trust store and that it is in place.

Make sure you have a `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property set and then check that the path actually leads to the trust store.

You can also enable SSL debugging by setting this system property `-Djavax.net.debug=all`.  Within the debug output you will notice it states that it cannot find the trust store.

Comment: The mean that the peer certificate wasn't found in or trusted by the trust store, which *was* found.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Server-Side issue.

Server side have **.crt** file for HTTPS,  here we have to do combine

```
cat your_domain.**crt** your_domain.**ca-bundle** >> ssl_your_domain_.crt
```

then restart.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

For me working fine.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I hadn't set `ca` file in my Node.js HTTPS server.  It was working with `key` and `cert` only on browser, but it seems like Java needs `ca` bundle (having two or three `----BEGIN ...` parts) file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this class and have no problem.

```java
public class WCFs
{
    // https://192.168.30.8/myservice.svc?wsdl
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "192.168.30.8";
    private static final String SERVICE = "/myservice.svc?wsdl";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/iWCFserviceMe/";


    public static Thread myMethod(Runnable rp)
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "myMethod";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("Message", "Https WCF Running...");
        return _call(rp,METHOD_NAME, request);
    }

    protected static HandlerThread _call(final RunProcess rp,final String METHOD_NAME, SoapObject soapReq)
    {
        final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        int TimeOut = 5*1000;

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.bodyOut = soapReq;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);

        final HttpsTransportSE httpTransport_net = new HttpsTransportSE(URL, 443, SERVICE, TimeOut);

        try
        {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() // use this section if crt file is handmake
            {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            KeyStore k = getFromRaw(R.raw.key, "PKCS12", "password");
            ((HttpsServiceConnectionSE) httpTransport_net.getServiceConnection()).setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory(k, "SSL"));


        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("wcfTd"+ Generator.getRandomNumber())
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                Object response = null;

                for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    response = send(envelope, httpTransport_net , METHOD_NAME, null);

                    try
                    {if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;}catch(Exception e){}

                    if(response != null)
                        break;

                    ThreadHelper.threadSleep(250);
                }

                if(response != null)
                {
                    if(rp != null)
                    {
                        rp.setArguments(response.toString());
                        h.post(rp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        return;

                    if(rp != null)
                    {
                        rp.setExceptionState(true);
                        h.post(rp);
                    }
                }

                ThreadHelper.stopThread(this);
            }
        };

        thread.start();

        return thread;
    }


    private static Object send(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope, HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport, String METHOD_NAME, List<HeaderProperty> headerList)
    {
        try
        {
            if(headerList != null)
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME, envelope, headerList);
            else
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME, envelope);

            Object res = envelope.getResponse();

            if(res instanceof SoapPrimitive)
                return (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            else if(res instanceof SoapObject)
                return ((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

        return null;
    }

    public static KeyStore getFromRaw(@RawRes int id, String algorithm, String filePassword)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = ResourceMaster.openRaw(id);
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(algorithm);
            keystore.load(inputStream, filePassword.toCharArray());
            inputStream.close();

            return keystore;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}

        return null;
    }

    public static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore trustKey, String SSLAlgorithm)
    {
        try
        {
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(trustKey);

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(SSLAlgorithm);//"SSL" "TLS"
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            return context.getSocketFactory();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be solution to your question but it will surely help others looking for similar issue like this one:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

You just need to check your Android Device's Date and Time, it should be fix the issue.
This resoled my problem.