# How to add SSL certificate in android using retrofit library

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit

I have done SSL certificate using native http library but how can I do with retrofit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31436459/4261176.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CertPathValidatorException : Trust anchor for certificate path not found - Retrofit Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273387/certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certificate-path-not-found-retro)