# how to add SSL certificates to okHttp mutual TLS connection?

Tags: java, ssl, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have a .pem and a .key files already that I dont want to install/import it locally, just tell my client to use them, is it possible? its not a self signed certificate

Basically, in my curl Im doing something like this:

```
curl --key mykey.key --cert mycert.pem https://someurl.com/my-endpoint
```

I have checked this answer

[How to make https request with ssl certificate in Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779533/how-to-make-https-request-with-ssl-certificate-in-retrofit)

also this https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java (but might not make sense since I dont get an object of the type I need)

Basically I have my okHttpClient

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(?, ?) //here I tried to call sslSocketFactory, trustManager following the example from the CustomTrust.java
    .build()
```

Any ideas for a solution?

Have checked this documentation as well but again the ssl part is not completed nor at the samples

https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/#customizing-trusted-certificates-kt-java

So I tried doing this (base on the okhttp samples)

```
private fun trustedCertificatesInputStream(): InputStream {
        val comodoRsaCertificationAuthority = (""
            + "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
            "-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
        return Buffer()
            .writeUtf8(comodoRsaCertificationAuthority)
            .inputStream()
    }


    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }


    fun createClient() : OkHttpClient {

        val trustManager: X509TrustManager
        val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory
        try {
            trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(trustedCertificatesInputStream())
            val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
            sslContext.init(null, arrayOf<TrustManager>(trustManager), null)
            sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory



        } catch (e: GeneralSecurityException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
            .connectTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    }


    @Throws(GeneralSecurityException::class)
    private fun trustManagerForCertificates(input: InputStream): X509TrustManager {
        val certificateFactory: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val certificates: Collection<Certificate?> = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(input)
        val password = "password".toCharArray() // Any password will work.
        val keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password)

        for ((index, certificate) in certificates.withIndex()) {
            val certificateAlias = index.toString()
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate)
        }
        // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
        val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password)

        val trustManagerFactory: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

        val trustManagers: Array<TrustManager> = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()
        return trustManagers[0]!! as X509TrustManager
    }

    @Throws(GeneralSecurityException::class)
    private fun newEmptyKeyStore(password: CharArray): KeyStore {
        return try {
            val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
            val inputStream: InputStream? = null // By convention, 'null' creates an empty key store.
            keyStore.load(inputStream, password)
            keyStore
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw AssertionError(e)
        }

    }
```

and I get an error of

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

searching about the error seems like I should install the SSL locally, which I should avoid to do it since I cannot install it that way in the server, is there any way I can make it work?

Answer (score 7):

Looking at your `curl` command and `java` code I see that they are not configured the same. Let's first have a look at your curl command and analyse it:

**your curl command:**

`curl --key mykey.key --cert mycert.pem https://someurl.com/my-endpoint`

**curl options explained:**

- key => your client private key
- cert => your client certificate chain
- cacert => trusted server certificates

Your `cacert` option is empty so if your curl passes it means it matched the server certificate based on the `default trusted certificates` which is available within curl. The default trusted certificate within curl may differ with the default trusted certificates within java and therefor it can result into different behaviour. I would recommend to add the server certificate to your curl command and java code snippet.

Based on your curl command we can translate the options to java:

**Mapping from curl to java**

- key => KeyManager
- cert => KeyManager
- cacert => TrustManager

The default java classes have limited support for parsing pem formatted private keys. As far as I know it can only parse unencrypted private keys. I can recommend Bouncy Castle to easily parse encrypted pem formatted private keys. The example below assumes you have an unencrypted private key.

**Option 1**

```java
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        InputStream trustedCertificateAsInputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/server-certificate.pem"), StandardOpenOption.READ);
        Certificate trustedCertificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(trustedCertificateAsInputStream);
        KeyStore trustStore = createEmptyKeyStore("secret".toCharArray());
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("server-certificate", trustedCertificate);

        String privateKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/mykey.key")), Charset.defaultCharset())
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        byte[] privateKeyAsBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyAsBytes);

        InputStream certificateChainAsInputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/mycert.pem"), StandardOpenOption.READ);
        Certificate certificateChain = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateChainAsInputStream);

        KeyStore identityStore = createEmptyKeyStore("secret".toCharArray());
        identityStore.setKeyEntry("client", keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec), "secret".toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificateChain});

        trustedCertificateAsInputStream.close();
        certificateChainAsInputStream.close();

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(identityStore, "secret".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManagers[0])
                .build();
    }

    public static KeyStore createEmptyKeyStore(char[] keyStorePassword) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, KeyStoreException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, keyStorePassword);
        return keyStore;
    }
}
```

The code is a bit verbose, but it should do the trick for you.

**Option 2**

If you prefer a less verbose alternative you can give the following snippet a try:

```java
X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager = PemUtils.loadIdentityMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/mycert.pem"), Paths.get("/path/to/mycert.pem"));
X509ExtendedTrustManager trustManager = PemUtils.loadTrustMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/server-certificate.pem"));

SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
          .withIdentityMaterial(keyManager)
          .withTrustMaterial(trustManager)
          .build();

SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslFactory.getSslSocketFactory();
X509ExtendedtrustManager trustManager = sslFactory.getTrustManager().orElseThrow();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
          .build();
```

The above library is maintained by me and you can find it here: [GitHub - SSLContext Kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart)

Comment: Thanks @Hakan54, this has been very helpful! To get the trusted server (root) certificates that are missing in the OP's original curl example you can use https://serverfault.com/a/661982 - IF you trust your network, that is ;-) Instead of piping to `openssl x509`pipe to `cat` or a file to get the certificate chain. Everything between the delimiters will be ignored when reading with the PemUtils.

Comment: @cheppsn you can also give the following example a try to extract server certificates from cli see here for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/68277430/6777695

Answer (score 3):

I presume you want to configure TLS mutual auth, and that's what they key is for?

Take a look at [okhttp-tls](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls) which has APIs for turning certificate and private keys into the corresponding Java objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I dont quite undertand the way I should implement it for this way since I dont have an intermediate certificate, any idea how could I do to make it work?

Comment: This [section](https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/https/#customizing-trusted-certificates-kt-java) documents how to add root certificates, but there's not mention of keys there. There's also a `HeldCertificate` class, but no example of how to use it; I suspect that's what you need.