# OkHttpClient certificate authorization

Tags: java, ssl, retrofit, okhttp

I stuck with problem how to authorize java client application that consume rest api and need to autorize by ceritication issued by internal CA. So I have CA certificate, then Client certificate and client private key generate by OpenSSL. I'm looking for guide/ example how to tell OkHttpClient to sign request with Client certificate to bypass Apache SSL autorization. All is done on internal network. Can you guys help me?! I tried so much ways that I'm lost. I need good example. The stack is Retrofit with OkHTTPClient.

here is example via cURL what I need to implement in java in smart way
https://downey.io/notes/dev/curl-using-mutual-tls/

**** SOLUTION BELOW ****

[how to add SSL certificates to okHttp mutual TLS connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224181/how-to-add-ssl-certificates-to-okhttp-mutual-tls-connection)

In my case was mistake in private key format. I got pkcs1 and it must by pkcs8.

Comment: Do you want to bypass (ignore) or sign the request? If signing, this documentation is pretty much what you need to do - https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/

Comment: I tried this and it's still telling me, apache didnt recieve certificate. So somehow I'm not sending client certificate.

Comment: What is telling you that apache did not receive the cert? Are there debug logs from your application that we can see?

Comment: Good news, problem solved. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224181/how-to-add-ssl-certificates-to-okhttp-mutual-tls-connection) is right solution to mtls communication. My problem was that I have private key in bad format for first try, so java wont cooperate. When I tranform key to right format, all works like a charm.