# Java okHttp 2-way handshake SSL

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

How can I put my certificate to sign REST API request, for 2-way handshake?

My code:

```
HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(url);
HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = httpUrl.newBuilder();
Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
        .url(httpUrlBuilder.build())
        .post(okhttp3.RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), body));
for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
    builder.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
}
Request request = builder.build();
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory()).build();
Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
String res =  response.body().string();
System.out.print("Response: " +res);
```

I'm using Spring Boot and the certificate is loaded by:

```ini
server.ssl.key-store=certFile.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
security.require-ssl=true
```

This code works correctly, but without certificate signing, it is useless for me.

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224181/how-to-add-ssl-certificates-to-okhttp-mutual-tls-connection ?

Comment: Make up your mind. Are you trying to (a) complete a 2-way TLS handshake or (b) sign the REST request? They aren't the same thing. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
  private String submitPostRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String body) throws Exception {

    OkHttpClient client = createOkHttpClient(pfxCert, pfxCertPass);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), body);
    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : headers.entrySet()) {
        builder.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
    }
    Request request = builder.build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        String responseContent = response.body().string();
        System.out.println(response.code());
        System.out.println("Server response: " + responseContent);

        return responseContent;
    }
}
```

Method:

```
private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient(String pfxFilePath, String pfxPassword) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    try (FileInputStream pfxInputStream = new FileInputStream(pfxFilePath)) {
        keyStore.load(pfxInputStream, pfxPassword.toCharArray());
    }

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pfxPassword.toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0]);

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: Evidently this is what the OP want,s as he as accepted the answer, but there is nothing here that constitutes 'sign[ing] the REST API request'.