# Updated SSL Certificate for android application

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, retrofit

How to update the SSL certificate for the app which is already in use. do we need to update whenever SSL expires? I'm using retrofit

Comment: So you are using a client certificate in the app? Or do you just use certificate pinning? If you can answer both questions with no and if you are using an certificate from a regular CA you don't need to do anything.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779533/how-to-make-https-request-with-ssl-certificate-in-retrofit for adding your ssl certificate to a retrofit request. As for logistics, you can keep a local copy of the ssl certificate which you use on first app install, after which you can setup a worker to fetch the new certificate when you need it

Comment: You can try out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507126/6777695 it looks similar to your question