# Certificate pinning not working with OkHttp on Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, retrofit, okhttp

Using `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0` with `com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0` on an Android app, trying to communicate with an server REST API over HTTPS, that uses a self signed certificate.

Server keystore has a private key and 2 certificates, the server's and a root certificate. `openssl s_client` output -

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=...OU=Dev/CN=example.com
   i:/C=... My CA/emailAddress=info@example.com
 1 s:/C=... My CA/emailAddress=info@example.com
   i:/C=... My CA/emailAddress=info@example.com
```

At the Android app, OkHttp is initialised with the root certificate's SHA1 signature -

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
        .add("example.com", "sha1/5d...3b=")
        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setCertificatePinner(certificatePinner);

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("https://example.com")
        .setClient(new OkClient(client))
        .build();
```

But when trying to send a request fails with exception -

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
        at $Proxy1.report(Unknown Source)
        ...
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:306)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
```

It's thrown at `com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector` when trying `sslSocket.startHandshake()`, even before `CertificatePinner` is used to check the received certificates.

I've made sure server has certificates installed correctly using `openssl` and with `curl --cacert root.pem`.

So why does OkHttp throw an exception before even trying to check if provided certificates are OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OkHttp does not support self signed certificates.

When using a certificate which is signed by a known CA, handshakes succeeds and then `CertificatePinner` makes sure the certificate chain contains at least one of the provided signatures. If none appear, it will throw an exception, stopping the request.

So it is possible to use a cert signed by a known CA and pin one of the certificates to make sure we're talking to the right server.

Comment: Yup. Certificate pinning doesn't replace the existing certificate verification; it complements it. You need to configure your client to trust your certificate; there are plenty of examples in the tests!

Comment: @JesseWilson and @Kof: can I ask a question, does `a known CA` mean a CA that is installed succesfully in Android phone (I can see it in `Trusted credentials - User`? Thanks

Comment: Probably, it's a CA that the device has its signature installed in its trusted CA database.

Comment: how can we know if our CA is trusted?

Comment: @Mr.Jay in browsers they have a list of trusted CAs, list can probably be looked up on the internet, if it's your CA (for self signing) you can trust yourself, trust me.

Answer (score 4):

**OkHttp does support self-signed certificates.**

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436459/4261176) to learn how to create a `SslSocket` that trusts only your certificate.

Comment: Another place to see example code is in OkHttp's recipe repo: [CustomTrust.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java). It provides more generic working code.