# Android send email through java mail api

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I have an android app that sends email through java mail api .The code works fine when my device is connected through mobile data but it doesn't work when device is connected to wifi 
Here is my Logcat report Please help[image]

Comment: check nested exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273387/certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certificate-path-not-found-retro

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ talks about [cert path exceptions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert), but if you're trying to connect to Gmail it's more likely that you're running into a [firewall on your local network](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).