# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found on Android 2.2

Tags: android, ssl

I am getting this issue when i replace my url with https...my url with http working fine but with https it's crashed,i search internet but not find any solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047414/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexcepti)

Comment: I have solved my problem with the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https

Comment: Then please post an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a CA for your certificate which is not known as trusted in the very old version of Android you are trying. More details might be given if you provide your URL.