# Fabric Crashlytics Error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: google-fabric

This Error is related to Fabric Crashlytics, not direct RestFul API consumptions.

I'm getting this error when initiating the Fabric Crashlytics on Android Emulator

```
E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1355)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.handleResponse(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:104)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:88)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.loadSettingsData(Settings.java:153)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:126)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:563)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:444)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
E/Fabric: at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
        ... 30 more
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        ... 42 more
E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
```

Any Idea how to resolve this, or add custom SSlSocketFactory to Fabric HttpRequest class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047414/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexcepti)

Comment: this is for general http request, this is coming from Fabric Crashlytics lib, my question is how to access HttpRequest classes inside this lib and customize it according to our network? @MikeBonnell

Comment: That's not something I'm an expert in. Fabric doesn't support http customization.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else experiencing this issue: This error occurred for me when the wifi password was outdated and my device switched to a different (open) network. Try switching to another (closed) network.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue, the same Crashlytics setup in Fabric and Firebase, tried with different versions of Crashlytics up to 2.9.2, it worked fine on API 22+, but not on API 21 and below. In the end, it is resolved by a workaround, not ideal and not recommended for production, which is bypassing the ssl check all together by calling the function below in the onCreate() in app's Application class.

```
public void trustAllCertificates() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                        return myTrustedAnchors;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

References: https://androidlad.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-trust-all-certificates-or-bypass.html